# What makes a distribution normal?

Tags: probability

What are the physical characteristics to a random variable which makes its distribution normal in nature??

P.S. Please do not explain the mathematics of a normal distribution.

Comment: If you want an answer without mathematics, what led you to pose this question in a mathematics community...?

Comment: Anyway, normal distribution describes fluctuation caused by a large quantity of almost uncorrelated, randomly behaving objects.

Comment: If you are not going to use mathematics, how do you define "normal distribution", and "random variable"?

Comment: Maybe your question should be rephrased as "Why normal distribution is a good/common candidate in modelling physical nature in the real world?" Part of the reason should be related to Central Limit Theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best physical characterization of the normal distribution is for the multivariate normal.  If you have a spherically (or elliptically) symmetric distribution with indepedent marginals (i.e., each random coordinate is independent of the others), it must be multivariate normal.

This was proved in 1808 by the Irish-American mathematician Robert Adrain.  See p. 294 of J Hoffmann-Jorgensen's *Probability with a View Toward Statistics, Vol 1*.